# Understanding 'Self' and instance creation in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand 'self' in python on a deeper level because while I use it, I find myself not understanding it in full.

Consider the code below

```
class FoodItems:

def __init__(self, other arguments):
some code

def main():
some code

item1 = FoodItems
item1.main()
```

For the method [ def main() ] I am not passing the parameter 'Self' in it and the code works when I call it. My understanding of 'Self' is that it has to be passed every time a method is created under the class. If I pass 'Self', and then call the method, I get the error ( missing 1 required positional argument: 'self')

Can some one explain this to me?

Now, the second part of the question, when it comes to creating instances,I cant tell the difference between calling an instance with  or without parentheses such as ( item1 = FoodItems Vs. item1=FoodItems() )

Note: When I use parantheses I get the error, missing 8 required positional arguments that have been initialized in the constructor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code isn't indented properly, and to create a new `FoodItems` object, you need to go `FoodItems()`.  Please could you fix this.

Comment: `item1 = FoodItems` *doesn't* create any instance, period. You’re just aliasing the class to a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, **self** is a reference to the instance of the class. It's used to access instance variables and call instance methods. When you define a method inside a class, you need to include the **self** parameter to work with the instance. However, when you call the method, you don't need to pass **self** explicitly, as Python does it for you.

Regarding your first question, when you don't pass **self** in the **main()** method definition, it becomes a static method. Static methods are methods that don't depend on the instance of the class and don't use the **self** parameter. Here's an example:

```
class FoodItems:
    def __init__(self, other_arguments):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        print("Static method called")

item1 = FoodItems()
item1.main()
```

In this case, you can call the **main()** method without passing **self**. However, you won't be able to access any instance variables or other instance methods within the **main()** method.

For the second part of your question, the difference between **item1 = FoodItems** and **item1 = FoodItems()** is that the first one assigns the **FoodItems** class itself to **item1**, while the second one creates a new instance of the **FoodItems** class and assigns it to **item1**.

When you use parentheses **(item1 = FoodItems())**, you're actually calling the constructor ****init**** of the class, which initializes a new object. If you get an error about missing positional arguments, it means that you need to pass the required arguments when creating a new instance. For example:

```
class FoodItems:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def main(self):
        print("Instance method called")

# Create a new instance of FoodItems with the required arguments
item1 = FoodItems("Apple")
item1.main()
```

In this case, you need to pass the **name** argument when creating a new instance of **FoodItems**. When you call the **main()** method, Python implicitly passes the instance as the self argument

Please checkout these articles for more background knowledge:
[Realpython.com blog](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) and the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).

Comment: Hi Luis thank you so much for the extensive explanation it is really great of you will hunt down more info in the links provided. Thanks again!